# Need a bat file to super hide folder in flash?

Tags: file, batch-file, hidden, super

I know I can super hide a folder by using the following codes in cmd:
attrib +S +H FolderName
But I need a .bat file to do this for me automatically when my flash is connedted to computer.

Comment: What system are you on? Usually, there is no bash on windows, but no bat files on linux. Do you need it on every computer (probably not possible) or only yours?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the flash drive letter (or range of probable letters) you can use

```
:LOOP
for %%a in (E: F: G:) do (
if exist %%a\FolderToHide attrib +s +h %%a\FolderToHide
)
timeout /t 5
goto :LOOP
```

The timeout is just so the batch doesn't overload the CPU cycles, and if your not sure about the drive letter just do `A:` to `Z:`.